# Tensorflow Linear Regression not converging to correct cost

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to implement multivariate linear regression in tensorflow (using the Boston Housing Dataset), but it seems like my cost function is converging and the wrong value (24000 in my case). I tried scaling the features, but it still hasn't worked. Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong? Here is the code:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

rate = 0.000000011
epochs = 100
errors = []

def load_data():
    boston = load_boston()

    bos = pd.DataFrame(boston.data)

    output = pd.DataFrame(boston.target)

    return [bos, output]

xS, yS = load_data()

m = len(yS)

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(xS, yS, test_size=0.2)

scaler = MinMaxScaler()
scaler.fit(x_train)
x_train = scaler.transform(x_train)
x_test = scaler.transform(x_test)

theta = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([len(xS.columns), 1]))
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[m, len(xS.columns)])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[m, 1])
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([m, 1]))

model = tf.matmul(tf.transpose(theta), tf.transpose(X)) + b

cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(y-model))/(2*m)

optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(rate).minimize(cost)

init = [tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.local_variables_initializer()]

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    for e in range(epochs):
        sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={X:xS, y:yS})
        loss = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={X:xS, y:yS})
        print("cost at step", e, loss)
        errors.append(loss)
        if errors[len(errors)-1] > errors[len(errors)-2]:
            break

    theta_temp = np.array(sess.run(theta))
    b_temp = np.array(sess.run(b))

plt.plot(list(range(len(errors))), errors)
plt.show()
h = np.transpose(np.add(np.matmul(np.transpose(theta_temp), np.transpose(xS)), np.transpose(b_temp)))
print(r2_score(h, yS))
```

Comment: What kind of crappy learning rate is `rate = 0.000000011`?

Comment: When I used larger learning rates (0.01, 0.1, etc.) the graph of gradient descent would blow up, showing that the learning rate was too large. This was the largest I could get it to for the graph to actually go down.

Comment: Yeah, there are way too many things wrong with this code. My advice is to take a step back and look at the docs. Or just use a linear estimator.

Comment: My idea of the code was to create a linear model from a rather low-level (instead of using sklearn or tf.estimator). Could you just tell me where I started to go wrong? I'm new to tensorflow so I don't really have any idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing most of the thing correctly. I will suggest the following changes in your code.

```
model = tf.matmul(X, theta) + b
```

Try this with a learning rate 0.001 and epoch 1000 and please report the result.

In your case where you are doing

`model = tf.matmul(tf.transpose(theta), tf.transpose(X)) + b`

you are making a mistake. First part of the right side is of size (1, m) and the second part is of size (m, 1). Then you are getting a some result because of broadcasting that you are not expecting. That is why you are seeing very bad results with a learning rate of 0.01 or 0.1.

My second suggestion is remove the break criterion.

`if errors[len(errors)-1] > errors[len(errors)-2]:
    break`

Stochastic gradients are noisy. There is no proof that you will always reduce the cost if you go into the less gradient direction (may be it is true for this convex problem but I have to think).

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

rate = 0.1
epochs = 100
errors = []

def load_data():
    boston = load_boston()

    bos = pd.DataFrame(boston.data)

    output = pd.DataFrame(boston.target)

    return [bos, output]

xS, yS = load_data()


x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(xS, yS, test_size=0.2)
m = len(y_train)

scaler = MinMaxScaler()
scaler.fit(x_train)
x_train = scaler.transform(x_train)
x_test = scaler.transform(x_test)

theta = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([len(xS.columns), 1]))
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[m, len(xS.columns)])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[m, 1])
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]))

model = tf.matmul(X, theta) + b

cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(y-model))/(2*m)

optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(rate).minimize(cost)

init = [tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.local_variables_initializer()]

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    for e in range(epochs):
        sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={X:x_train, y:y_train})
        loss = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={X:x_train, y:y_train})
        print("cost at step", e, loss)
        errors.append(loss)
```

[image]

Comment: I've already tried this, but it still doesn't work. When I implement your changes (changing the tf.matmul() line, chaging epochs, changing rate, and stochastic gradients) the cost still blows up until NAN (past inf). I feel like there's something else going on here, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I noticed that even though you defined a minmax scalar you are not using it. Try the following code that I have appended below my previous answer. You also used the wrong size of the bias. The bias is just a constant but you were using the bias as the same size as in the batch size.

Comment: Wow! Thanks! The bias may have been the issue, but regardless, I get it now.